# Saber qué celda se ha seleccionado en un Jtable Java

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Necesito obtener la celda que se ha seleccionado de un Jtable y después cambiarle el color de fondo a la misma celda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

table.getSelectedRow() obtendrá la fila seleccionada.

table.getSelectedColumns() obtendrá columnas seleccionadas.

getValueAt(rowIndex,columnIndex) dará el valor presente en la fila seleccionada para cada columna.

Ejemplo

```
int rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
int colIndex = table.getSelectedColumn();
```

Comment: Gracias! me sirvió mucho 0/